# Set start time and end time to show content Jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to set a start time and end time in Jquery, for example, if it is between 17:34 and 18:56 I would like to show content. I found this way of finding the current time:

```
  $.getJSON("http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz="+timezone+"&callback=?",
    function(data){
      ......
    })
```

**data.hour** returns hour,
 **data.minute** returns the minute,
 **data.second** returns the second.

I was thinking of maybe from this converting the time into milliseconds and then creating an if statement based on the milliseconds? But how would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply use new Date().UTC() ? Why ask a server ?

Comment: if I used new Date() does it not retrieve the date from the user's OS or browser, making it easy for them to manipulate the time?

Comment: Agreed, unless you don't trust the client at all then just getting the time from them isn't a big deal, as a sidenote you can always verify the datetime immediately.

Comment: If you do the tests browserside in JavaScript, it **is** easy to manipulate what's done. Querying a distant server for the time doesn't make it better or safer.

Comment: Surely it is safer, because if I change the OS time then I can manipulate it.

Comment: If you have content that the user should only see between 17:34 and 18:56, then you should use the client side `Date()` to request that content from the server only during that window.  Remember, all client side code is open to review and possible manipulation.  **Anything client side can be viewed at any time**, if the user is sufficiently determined.

Comment: well Date() doesn't help then because I don't want someone to change their time on their computer then see the content.

Comment: neither does querying the server like you did because that's javascript which is clientside code, meaning someone could easily just manipulate the results of that request...If the security of the app is at this great of a risk you'll need To do the secure methods on the server or use Oauth2

Comment: > Surely it is safer, because if I change the OS time then I can manipulate it. -- And if I change server response via web-debugger such as fiddler or even replace your function right from browser console, I can manipulate it as well. JS is not safe in any way, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date()
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
var startdate_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  17, 34, 0);
var enddate_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  18, 56, 0);

if((now_utc > startdate_utc) && (now_utc < enddate_utc)) {
  // Show content   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Users can hack your JavaScript and modify the logic to retrieve the content you wish to protect if you do this client side (using JavaScript/jQuery).

You will have to put the time validation on the server side to avoid manipulation by developers or hackers. Even an Ajax call to get the date and time will not help because I can put a breakpoint in the success function of that Ajax call, and modify the result before allowing the rest of your code to run. In fact, it's a lot safer for me to do this than it is for me to modify my system time because it doesn't affect anything else on my computer.